# Using R and regex to remove special characters from a string

Tags: r, regex

I'm using R and have a vector of characters in a data.frame, I need to remove some special characters from specific columns. The data.frame is a table of college football scores. Some of the team names start with '([0-9)' or whatever ranking that particular team currently is. I want to remove the ranking before these team names so only the team names remain. I'm close to getting it with this code below, but I'm struggling with removing the '()' and also having leftover ' ' spaces in front of team names. Any ideas?

```
# remove the numbers before team names
rr <- Scores$Winner
rr <- gsub("\\([0-9]\\)","",rr)
rr <- gsub("\\([0-9][0-9]\\)","",rr)
rr
```

Heres an example of the data.frame

```
> dput(Scores[1:50,])
structure(list(Rk = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"), Wk = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), Date = c("Aug 26, 2017", 
"Aug 26, 2017", "Aug 26, 2017", "Aug 26, 2017", "Aug 26, 2017", 
"Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", 
"Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", 
"Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", "Aug 31, 2017", 
"Aug 31, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", 
"Sep 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", "Sep 1, 2017", 
"Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", 
"Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", 
"Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", 
"Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", 
"Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017", "Sep 2, 2017"), 
    Time = c("3:00 PM", "2:30 PM", "6:00 PM", "7:30 PM", "10:00 PM", 
    "10:30 PM", "8:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:30 PM", "9:00 PM", 
    "9:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:30 PM", 
    "6:30 PM", "6:00 PM", "9:30 PM", "8:00 PM", "6:30 PM", "8:00 PM", 
    "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM", "9:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "8:00 PM", "3:30 PM", 
    "11:00 PM", "7:30 PM", "3:45 PM", "12:20 PM", "12:00 PM", 
    "12:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "6:00 PM", "10:00 PM", "6:15 PM", 
    "11:59 PM", "9:00 PM", "12:00 PM", "12:00 PM", "8:00 PM", 
    "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "7:10 PM", "4:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "9:30 PM"
    ), Day = c("Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Thu", "Thu", 
    "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", "Thu", 
    "Thu", "Thu", "Fri", "Fri", "Fri", "Fri", "Fri", "Fri", "Fri", 
    "Fri", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", 
    "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", 
    "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat"), Winner = c("Brigham Young", 
    "Colorado State", "Hawaii", "(19) South Florida", "(14) Stanford", 
    "Arizona State", "Arkansas", "Central Michigan", "Cincinnati", 
    "Connecticut", "Idaho", "Memphis", "Minnesota", "(2) Ohio State", 
    "Tennessee State", "Toledo", "Utah", "Wake Forest", "Army", 
    "Boston College", "Colorado", "Eastern Michigan", "Navy", 
    "Syracuse", "(8) Washington", "(9) Wisconsin", "Air Force", 
    "(1) Alabama", "Alabama-Birmingham", "Arizona", "(12) Auburn", 
    "Boise State", "California", "Central Florida", "(5) Clemson", 
    "Coastal Carolina", "Duke", "Fresno State", "(15) Georgia", 
    "Hawaii", "Howard", "Illinois", "Iowa", "Iowa State", "James Madison", 
    "Kansas", "(20) Kansas State", "Kentucky", "Liberty", "(13) Louisiana State"
    ), Pts = c("20", "58", "38", "42", "62", "37", "49", "30", 
    "26", "27", "28", "37", "17", "49", "17", "47", "37", "51", 
    "64", "23", "17", "24", "42", "50", "30", "59", "62", "24", 
    "38", "62", "41", "24", "35", "61", "56", "38", "60", "66", 
    "31", "41", "43", "24", "24", "42", "34", "38", "55", "24", 
    "48", "27"), c("", "", "@", "@", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "@", "@", "", "", "", "", "@", "", "", "@", "", 
    "@", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "@", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "@", "", "", "", "@", "", "", "@", "@", ""), Loser = c("Portland State", 
    "Oregon State", "Massachusetts", "San Jose State", "Rice", 
    "New Mexico State", "Florida A&M", "Rhode Island", "Austin Peay", 
    "Holy Cross", "Sacramento State", "Louisiana-Monroe", "Buffalo", 
    "Indiana", "Georgia State", "Elon", "North Dakota", "Presbyterian", 
    "Fordham", "Northern Illinois", "Colorado State", "Charlotte", 
    "Florida Atlantic", "Central Connecticut State", "Rutgers", 
    "Utah State", "Virginia Military Institute", "(3) Florida State", 
    "Alabama A&M", "Northern Arizona", "Georgia Southern", "Troy", 
    "North Carolina", "Florida International", "Kent State", 
    "Massachusetts", "North Carolina Central", "Incarnate Word", 
    "Appalachian State", "Western Carolina", "Nevada-Las Vegas", 
    "Ball State", "Wyoming", "Northern Iowa", "East Carolina", 
    "Southeast Missouri State", "Central Arkansas", "Southern Mississippi", 
    "Baylor", "Brigham Young"), Pts = c("6", "27", "35", "22", 
    "7", "31", "7", "27", "14", "20", "6", "29", "7", "21", "10", 
    "13", "16", "7", "6", "20", "3", "7", "19", "7", "14", "10", 
    "0", "7", "7", "24", "7", "13", "30", "17", "3", "28", "7", 
    "0", "10", "18", "40", "21", "3", "24", "14", "16", "19", 
    "17", "45", "0"), TV = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), Notes = c("LaVell Edwards Stadium - Provo, Utah", 
    "Sonny Lubrick Field at Colorado State Stadium - Fort Collins, Colorado", 
    "Warren McGuirk Alumni Stadium - Amherst, Massachusetts", 
    "CEFCU Stadium - San Jose, California", "Allianz Stadium - Sydney, AUS", 
    "Sun Devil Stadium - Tempe, Arizona", "War Memorial Stadium - Little Rock, Arkansas", 
    "Kelly/Shorts Stadium - Mount Pleasant, Michigan", "Nippert Stadium - Cincinnati, Ohio", 
    "Pratt & Whitney Stadium at Rentschler Field - East Hartford, Connecticut", 
    "Kibbie-Asui Activity Center - Moscow, Idaho", "Liberty Bowl Memorial Stadium - Memphis, Tennessee", 
    "TCF Bank Stadium - Minneapolis, Minnesota", "Memorial Stadium \"The Rock\" - Bloomington, Indiana", 
    "Georgia State Stadium - Atlanta, Georgia", "Glass Bowl - Toledo, Ohio", 
    "Rice-Eccles Stadium - Salt Lake City, Utah", "BB&T Field - Winston-Salem, North Carolina", 
    "Michie Stadium - West Point, New York", "Huskie Stadium - DeKalb, Illinois", 
    "Sports Authority Field - Denver, Colorado", "Rynearson Stadium - Ypsilanti, Michigan", 
    "FAU Football Stadium - Boca Raton, Florida", "Carrier Dome - Syracuse, New York", 
    "High Point Solutions Stadium - Piscataway, New Jersey", 
    "Camp Randall Stadium - Madison, Wisconsin", "Falcon Stadium - Colorado Springs, Colorado", 
    "Mercedes-Benz Stadium - Atlanta, Georgia", "Legion Field - Birmingham, Alabama", 
    "Arizona Stadium - Tucson, Arizona", "Jordan-Hare Stadium - Auburn, Alabama", 
    "Albertsons Stadium - Boise, Idaho", "Kenan Memorial Stadium - Chapel Hill, North Carolina", 
    "", "Clemson Memorial Stadium - Clemson, South Carolina", 
    "Brooks Stadium - Conway, South Carolina", "Wallace Wade Stadium - Durham, North Carolina", 
    "Bulldog Stadium - Fresno, California", "Sanford Stadium - Athens, Georgia", 
    "Aloha Stadium - Honolulu, Hawaii", "Sam Boyd Stadium - Las Vegas, Nevada", 
    "Memorial Stadium - Champaign, Illinois", "Kinnick Stadium - Iowa City, Iowa", 
    "Jack Trice Stadium - Ames, Iowa", "Dowdy-Ficklen Stadium - Greenville, North Carolina", 
    "Memorial Stadium - Lawrence, Kansas", "Bill Snyder Family Stadium - Manhattan, Kansas", 
    "M. M. Roberts Stadium - Hattiesburg, Mississippi", "McLane Stadium - Waco, Texas", 
    "Mercedes-Benz Superdome - New Orleans, Louisiana")), .Names = c("Rk", 
"Wk", "Date", "Time", "Day", "Winner", "Pts", "", "Loser", "Pts", 
"TV", "Notes"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Match `\(\d+\) ` and replace with "" https://regex101.com/r/Vhl5oe/1

Comment: `Scores$Winner <- sub('\\(\\d+\\) ', '', Scores$Winner)`

Comment: or `gsub('.*\\) ', '', scores$Winner)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex and replace it with the empty string:

`^\\([0-9]+\\)\\s+` or `^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+`

this will remove the starting digits surrounded by parenthesis and it will trim the beginning of your string.

Example:

```
(3) Florida State -> Florida State
```

Comment: gsub("^\\(\\d+\\)\\s+", "", Scores$Winner )